# Figuring out Latitude and Longitude from XY Image

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, latitude-longitude, proj4js

I'm having difficulty calculating the latitude and longitude values of an image that I am hosting inside of a div tag on my webpage.  I can easily figure out the x,y (pixel) coordinates of the image and save them to a variable inside of my script.  Here's the tricky part...

The map is *not* a mercator projection, so I cannot simply linearly interpolate the x,y pixel coordinates to lat and lon values.  However, I do have the luxury of knowing the latitude and longitude of all four corners of the image (see posted diagram), projection of the map on the image, central meridian, and latitude of origin.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/xcGQCk1.png]

The 800x600 pixel image is of the U.S. and I am basically trying to capture the latitude and longitude on click by passing the x,y pixel coordinates.  I am assuming I will need some sort of transformation function.

Comment: you could play with the precision to give an approximate base on the extrapolation. how precise do you wan to be ?

Comment: I'd like to be as precise as possible, but I'm open to any ideas.  What do you mean by, "approximate base on the extrapolation"?

Comment: GIS (Geographic Information System) at http://gis.stackexchange.com/ would be a more appropriate site for this question.

Comment: two questions : how do you get the map and the GPS coordinates ? how precise are the coordinate of the 4 points?

Comment: They are precise.  The map is a static GIF image, and I can pass the x,y pixel coordinates on mouse click from the div tag.

Comment: Does [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StereographicProjection.html) help you? (see eqs. (4) and (5))

Comment: I see the equations but I'm not sure I understand how to use them or how they would help.

Comment: Okay, yes, eqn 4 and 5 certainly help.  Only problem now is that those equations are dependent on rho and c.  Rho is easily calculated with x and y, but c is dependent on R, which is then dependent on something called the conformal latitude.  Not sure I can figure out this R piece...

Comment: If 'R' is simply the radius of the Earth, it doesn't specify the units to use?

Answer (score 0):

It might (for the sake of your sanity) be easier to have use a map API like Leaflet or Google maps on the page and just fix the position and then use the LatLng from the on click event.

A quick look at the Leaflet.js API suggests that's possible and it looks like you can do it with google maps too. It's a little bit of a fiddle to make sure you've disabled all the drag and zoom possibilities. BUT it seems, to me, much easier as all the projection work is done for you.

Unless there really is a burning reason why you need THAT image of the US. But even then you might be able to overlay the picture on the map.

Comment: I am facing somewhat the same issue where i wanted to find lat longs from images. I'm doing analytics on images which is not possible on google maps. but once i do my analytics i need to find the lat long of the position ive identified.